# How to do a print version of 3D objects with templates? (c++)

Tags: c++, templates, multidimensional-array

I guess you have seen this particular function:

```
template<typename T> void print(const T& cont){
    for (auto &i: cont)
        std::cout << i << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

It print's almost all type of containers like `std::list`. Now i wanna create one that prints (as example) 3D `std::vector`, look at this fantasy:

```
template<typename T1, typename T2> void print(const T1<T2>&);
```

But of course this is not how templates work. How to do that? And not less important: is any difference of doing that in c++17 and pre-c++17?

Comment: I see you accepted the answer :) But what do you mean by differences between c++17 and before that?

Comment: @cigien I hear that the reason a lot of compilers are in c++14 by default (even if they have c++20) is because a lot of project get broken because of the differences in templates in c++17 and after, that's why. But per now i see that this works perfectly in c++17

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I've heard of that. I wouldn't worry about it :)

Comment: @cigien Maybe, but btw i see this code does not work in c++14 due to other reasons. I try to change the flag to `-std=c++14` and it doesnt compile. But anyways, that's an amazing solution!

Comment: Huh, you're right. I don't actually know why. It should work in c++14 :p

Comment: We get this information by clang: `template template parameter using 'typename' is a C++17 extension`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223220/discussion-between-cigien-and-franz-kafka).

Comment: Ok, figured it out :) Not sure *why* the original didn't work, but now it works all the way back to c++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write the following template overloads, one that prints a 1-D range, and one that prints an N-D range by printing each nested (N-1)D range in a loop:

```
template<template<typename...> class Range,  
      // ^                         ^ 
      // Note the template template parameter
         typename T> 
void print(Range<T> const & cont)  // #1
{
    for (auto const & i : cont)
        std::cout << i << " ";    // print 1-D range
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

template<template<typename...> class RangeOut, 
         template<typename...> class RangeIn, 
         typename T> 
void print(RangeOut<RangeIn<T>> const & cont) // #2
{
    for (auto const &i: cont)
        print(i);              // call print overload:
                               // calls #1 if RangeIn is 1-D range
                               // calls #2 otherwise 
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Now you can print containers (ranges) of arbitrary dimensionality, and composed of heterogenous types, e.g:

```
std::vector<std::list<std::vector<int>>> vlv{{{1,2}, {3}} ,{{4,5}, {6}}};
print(vlv); // ok
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5KcGfE).